# is it possible to use Auth0 internally in Angular 2:

Tags: angular, auth0

is it possible to use Auth0 service internally in my Angular 2 APP, what i mean is simply manage the authentification with cookies without accessing the service externally, in my index.html i have this :

```
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-8.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without accessing the service externally"? Do you mean without making any connections to the Auth0 servers?

Comment: exactly, i want to simply manage the authentification locally

Comment: So you want to use the "Lock" login screen, without using the Auth0 service?

Comment: yeah, i want to manage the sessions with the lock login

Comment: Short answer, no. Longer answer, "Lock" isn't about managing sessions, in fact, no aspect of Auth0 is about managing sessions, it's a *token* based authentication platform. Secondly, the key here is that Auth0 is a *platform*, you need the Auth0 service in order to get anything meaningful done. That said, why not just use the service?

Comment: thank's for the answer man :)